# What does it mean to encode some statement in Theory of Natural Numbers $Th(\mathbb{N})$?

Tags: incompleteness

For example Godel's Incompleteness Theorem says *"Some statement in  $Th(\mathbb{N})$ has no proof".*

Consider sentence "This sentence is not provable".
We can encode this sentence in $Th(\mathbb{N})$.

Thus, *"This sentence is not provable"* $ \in Th(\mathbb{N})$. But if this sentence is TRUE then it is NOT provable.

$\therefore$ we have some true statements in $Th(\mathbb{N})$ that we cannot prove.

Here I do NOT understand what it means "We can encode 'This sentence is not provable' in $Th(\mathbb{N})$"

How can we encode some sentence in Natural Numbers? I am totally lost here.

Another idea I heard that relates to the same problem is:
*"Given $M$ and $x$, we want to construct a sentence $Y$ in the language of number theory that says '$M$ does not halt on $x$'. This will be possible because the language of number theory is strong enough to talk about Turing Machines and whether they halt or not".*

How it is even possible to talk about Turing Machines in the Theory of Naural Numbers?
I appreciate if you can help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose I have some correspondence of letters and symbols with natural numbers (something like $"a"=1$, $"b"=2$, ..., " "$=27$, ..., $"\wedge"=235$, $"\implies"=413$, &c. (and since we use only finitely many symbols, I have enough natural numbers to do so).

Uniqueness of prime factorisation means that I can then produce a unique natural number corresponding to each sentence of finite length, by raising the $n$th prime to the number corresponding to the $n$th character in the sentence (e.g. the natural corresponding to "ab" could be $2^13^2=6$). This construction is often called the statement's *Gödel number*.

---

The idea of Turing machines here is that you give the Turing machine some statement's Gödel number, and it attempts to prove the corresponding statement. The statement is *decidable* if the Turing Machine will halt on it. It turns out that the decidability of a statement is not predictable by a Turing machine in finite time, IIRC.

Comment: I am not fully clear on "TM attempts to prove the corresponding statement". Like what does it mean? I am also not sure what it means for a statement to be decidable. I know language can be decidable if we have a decider machine s.t. it returns TRUE if input $\in$ language or FALSE if input $\notin$ language. But the notion of statement to be decidable confuses me.